# Vue + tailwind Accordion with transition

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I tried to create Accordion component. But my animation with tailwind Not work

`[Codepen](https://codepen.io/maytad/pen/ExNbyrQ)`

Comment: Hello. Start here (VueJS implementation), then make the CSS part with Tailwind: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html